# Hackerrank Insertion Sort Part 2

Tags: java, programming-challenge, sorting, insertion-sort

I have started learning Java recently and was looking into the challenges on sorting on Hackerrank.I solved the following problem[Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insertionsort2) on Insertion Sort.

The challenge was :

> In Insertion Sort Part 1, you sorted one element into an array. Using the same approach repeatedly, can you sort an entire unsorted array?
>
> Guideline: You already can place an element into a sorted array. How can you use that code to build up a sorted array, one element at a time? Note that in the first step, when you consider an element with just the first element - that is already "sorted" since there's nothing to its left that is smaller.
>
> In this challenge, don't print every time you move an element. Instead, print the array after each iteration of the insertion-sort, i.e., whenever the next element is placed at its correct position.
>
> Since the array composed of just the first element is already "sorted", begin printing from the second element and on.
>
> Input Format
> There will be two lines of input:
>
> - the size of the array
> - a list of numbers that makes up the array
>
> Output Format :
> On each line, output the entire array at every iteration.

Sample Input:

```
6
1 4 3 5 6 2
```

Sample Output:

```
 1 4 3 5 6 2 
 1 3 4 5 6 2 
 1 3 4 5 6 2 
 1 3 4 5 6 2 
 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I am trying to get better at writing good code for my solutions..Please give me your suggestions .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InsertionSortPart2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = keyboard.nextInt();

    int[] array = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = keyboard.nextInt();

    }

    array = insertionsort(array);

}

private static int[] insertionsort(int[] a) {

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        // set key to value at index i
        int key = a[i];
        // set j as i-1 to look for previous element
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && a[j] > key) {
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }

        a[j + 1] = key;
        for (int f = 0; f < a.length; f++) {
            System.out.print(a[f] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    return a;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty good. The biggest problem is consistent indentation. Everything inside of your class should be indented one level; this includes the main method and your `insertionsort` method.

> ```
> private static int[] insertionsort(int[] a) {
>
>     for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
>         // set key to value at index i
>         int key = a[i];
>         // set j as i-1 to look for previous element
>         int j = i - 1;
>         while (j >= 0 && a[j] > key) {
>             a[j + 1] = a[j];
>             j--;
>         }
>
>         a[j + 1] = key;
>         for (int f = 0; f < a.length; f++) {
>             System.out.print(a[f] + " ");
>         }
>         System.out.println();
>     }
>
>     return a;
>   }
> ```

Indented better:

```
private static int[] insertionsort(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        // set key to value at index i
        int key = a[i];
        // set j as i-1 to look for previous element
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && a[j] > key) {
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }

        a[j + 1] = key;
        for (int f = 0; f < a.length; f++) {
            System.out.print(a[f] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    return a;
}
```

---

Good job on making the `insertionsort` function static. However, Java's naming convention is camelCase: `insertionSort`. I could have misread it as `insert ions ort` and gotten confused.

---

> private static int[] insertionsort(int[] a) {

The fact that you are returning an `int[]` makes it appear as if you don't modify the input array `a` (which *would* be better named `toSort`); however, you modify `a` and then return it. I strongly recommend either doing one or the other. If you *don't* want to modify the input, then you could do it as follows:

```
private static int[] insertionSort(int[] toSort) {
    int[] a = Arrays.copyOf(toSort, toSort.length); // needs to import java.util.Arrays
```

If you do want to modify the input, I would declare the method it as follows:

```
private static void insertionSort(int[] a) {
```

---

Additionally, your sort function should only sort, not print.

Here's the final result

```
private static void insertionSort(int[] toSort) {
    for (int i = 1; i < toSort.length; i++) {
        // set key to value at index i
        int key = toSort[i];
        // set j as i-1 to look for previous element
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && toSort[j] > key) {
            toSort[j + 1] = toSort[j];
            j--;
        }

        toSort[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

---

### Going further

Insertion sort is a nice sorting algorithm that works for much more than just `int`s; you can sort `double`s, `BigInteger`s, or even user-defined objects. Why not generify the function? You could do the following:

```
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void insertionSort(T[] toSort) {
    for (int i = 1; i < toSort.length; i++) {
        // set key to value at index i
        T key = toSort[i];
        // set j as i-1 to look for previous element
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && toSort[j].compareTo(key) > 0) {
            toSort[j + 1] = toSort[j];
            j--;
        }

        toSort[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

private static <T> void insertionSort(T[] toSort, Comparator<T> compare) {
    for (int i = 1; i < toSort.length; i++) {
        // set key to value at index i
        T key = toSort[i];
        // set j as i-1 to look for previous element
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && compare.compare(toSort[j], key) > 0) {
            toSort[j + 1] = toSort[j];
            j--;
        }

        toSort[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

This should allow you to sort arbitrarily typed arrays, except for the primitive types, unfortunately (although I did not compile the code).

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is quite fine. Some minor improvements are possible.

The `insertionsort` method doesn't need to return the array. It's not required by the problem, and it's pointless anyway, as the method modifies the input array.

In the `main` method you called the array `array`. That's not a very useful name, too generic.  Inside `insertionsort` it's even worse just the letter `a`. A better name in both places would be for example `nums`.

The inner `while` loop would be better as a `for` loop. The reason is, with a for loop it's easier to not forget to decrement the loop variable:

```
for (; j >= 0 && nums[j] > key; --j) {
```

Also, you set `j = i - 1`, and then you have to remember to use `a[j + 1]` in two places. It would be slightly simpler to use `j = i` and rearrange the rest accordingly.

Lastly, the printing of the array really belongs to a separate helper method.

Answer (score 2):

- **No naked loops**

  The inner loop implements an `insert` algorithm, and deserves a name. Factor it out into a method.

  It may or may not incur a performance penalty; I don't know how good Java is with function call inlining. With C I wouldn't think twice.
- **Insertion**

  The loop condition `j >= 0 && a[j] > key` checks for valid index on each iteration. Consider splitting insertion into 2 branches:

  ```
  if (a[0] > key) {
      shift_right_by_one(a, i);
      a[0] = key;
  } else {
      // This loop shall also become a method `unguarded_insert`
      while (a[j] > key) {
          a[j + 1] = a[j];
          --j;
      }
  }
  ```

  The `while` loop is known as `unguarded insertion`: since we ensure that `a[0] < key` the loop is guaranteed to terminate correctly, and uses twice as less comparisons.

Comment: Java would not inline it at the beginning, but after it figured out that it was being repeatedly called, it would go ahead and inline (since the method is small)